# How did the lady with the revolver see the hollow?

Tags: plot-explanation, miss-peregrines-home-for-peculiar

At the beginning of *Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children*, there is a lady that drives Jake to his grandfather's house. After Jake finds his grandfather laying in the woods, she gets her revolver out of her car. She shoots at the hollow.

**Was she peculiar and could see the hollow? Or was she just shooting because she was scared -- and didn't actually see it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jake saw the hollow stalking up behind his coworker and shouted "Shelley!  Behind you!"

Shelley fired blindly, in several directions.  She was just a normal human being, unable to see the hollow in any direct manner - aiming wherever she saw indications of movement or areas of solid darkness large enough to conceal a human-sized threat.

Notice that she fired all six shots straight ahead - chest-height for her, mid-calf for the hollow.  Had she actually perceived the hollow (not even actually seeing it, but surmising its position relative to her), she would unquestionably been firing at an upward angle.

More to the point: If she had perceived the hollow in the slightest, she wouldn't have stared so pointedly at Jake as if he were a complete blathering idiot - feeling like an idiot for emptying her revolver for 'no reason'.

Answer (score -1):

So as far as I'm concerned with Shelly there is  a huge plot hole. She goes from being able to swerve her vehicle around a hollow and saying "that guy gave me the heebie-jeebies" to not being able to see the hollow which attacks Jake's granddad. I'm honestly curious about if she may have been a peculiar without ever knowing it. The only way to know for certain is if she ever found her way into a loop which as of what I know she never has...